# SQL - Remove Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table structure:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| Column One | Column Two | Column Three | Column Four |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1001       | 6000       | 3000         | 200         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1001       | 6000       | 3000         | 200         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1001       | 6000       | 3000         | 200         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1001       | 6000       | 3000         | 202         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2001       | 6000       | 3000         | 100         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2001       | 6000       | 3000         | 100         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2001       | 6000       | 3000         | 100         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2001       | 6000       | 3000         | 102         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

As you see my table has a number of unique rows where the values of Column One-Four are consistent. However, it should be noted it has a number of 'nearly' unique rows where the values of Column One-Three are consistent.

I need a query to remove duplicate rows only where the entire row is unique.

My expected result would be:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| Column One | Column Two | Column Three | Column Four |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1001       | 6000       | 3000         | 200         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1001       | 6000       | 3000         | 202         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2001       | 6000       | 3000         | 100         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2001       | 6000       | 3000         | 102         |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I have the following query, but its not return any results:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE Column One NOT IN (SELECT min(Column One) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY Column One, Column Two, Column Three, Column Four);
```

Comment: By the way: Do you really want duplicates in your table? If not, then you should place a unique constraint on it, so duplicate inserts fail. (You'd have to remove duplicates from the table first, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for distinct rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `select distinct`:

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4
from table_name t;
```